# except ValueError isnt working in my code i dont know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

i included ValueError to make sure the user inputs an integer but it states unbound local error and states that the variable is referenced before the assignment

```
def bagTotal():
    while True:
        try:
            bagCount = int(input("Now we just need the number of bags you wish to take with you: "))          
        except ValueError:
            print("Please input a number")
            print("")
        if (bagCount <= 2):
            print("As stated before the first bag is free")
            print(name,",your total is","$%>2F"%ticket)
            print("")
            print("")
            restart()
        else:
            bagTotal = (bagCount - 1) * bagFee
            ticketTotal = bagTotal + ticketamount
            print(name,", your new total is","$%.2f"%ticketTotal)
            print("")
            print("")
            restart()
```

Comment: Please post some code and indicate what language it is. As your question stands I have no idea what you are discussing.

Comment: my bad im using python and im not sure how to post my code i tried earlier but it came out weird

Comment: You need to select your code and push the **`{}`** button on the toolbar, or manually indent everything four spaces. Try posting and hopefully someone will tidy it up if not perfect.

Comment: ok thanks just posted the code

Comment: my python version is 3.5

Comment: I added the `[python]` tag so the code gets coloured. A quick fix is to add `continue` as the last line of the `except` block so you jump to the start of the loop.

Comment: awesome man it works now just one more question i have another mod that asks for the ticketamount as a variable that is later used in the mod i provided but it said ticketamount is not defined

Comment: Is `ticketamount` a global? If not, it should be a parameter, etc. BTW, `if (bagCount <= 2):` - that gives me up to two free bags... Finally, rather than `restart()`, `break` or `return` would most likely be better.

Comment: ok problem fixed i just assumed that ticketamount would carry over but i changed it to a global and the code worked perfect thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you were to get a ValueError, the program would continue and run your `if` statements and such before you went to the next loop of the while loop.  You only want that code to run if you didn't get an error, so your code should look like this:

```
def bagTotal():
    while True:
        try:
            bagCount = int(input("Now we just need the number of bags you wish to take with you: "))
            if (bagCount <= 2):
                print("As stated before the first bag is free")
                print(name,",your total is","$%>2F"%ticket)
                print("")
                print("")
                restart()
            else:
                bagTotal = (bagCount - 1) * bagFee
                ticketTotal = bagTotal + ticketamount
                print(name,", your new total is","$%.2f"%ticketTotal)
                print("")
                print("")
                restart()          
        except ValueError:
            print("Please input a number")
            print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code, please check, I have commented few of the lines and also used some variables that
I saw in your code to make it working in my system.

```
def bagTotal():
    # The below 4 initializations are just
    # to stop errors in your problem, you use your own values
    bagFee = 100      
    ticketamount = 60 
    name = 'Rampel Jons'
    ticket = 70

    while True:
        try:
            bagCount = int(input("Now we just need the number of bags you wish to take with you: "))          
            if (bagCount <= 2):
                print("As stated before the first bag is free")
                print(name,",your total is","$%>2F"%ticket)
                print("")
                print("")
                restart() 
            else:
                bagTotal = (bagCount - 1) * bagFee
                ticketTotal = bagTotal + ticketamount
                print(name,", your new total is","$%.2f"%ticketTotal)
                print("")
                print("")
                restart() 
        except ValueError:
            print("Please input a number")
            print("")

# call
bagTotal()

# Now we just need the number of bags you wish to take with you: 5
# Rampel Jons , your new total is $460.00


# Now we just need the number of bags you wish to take with you: 7
# Rampel Jons , your new total is $660.00


# Now we just need the number of bags you wish to take with you: 9
# Rampel Jons , your new total is $860.00


# Now we just need the number of bags you wish to take with you: fjjfjf
# Please input a number

# Now we just need the number of bags you wish to take with you:
```

Comment: im sorry this is only part of my code there is another mod called restart() that gives the user the option to input more bags for a different ticket